# Where can I find the Java library for Spreadsheets API 3.0?

Tags: gdata, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

According to the documentation it can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/hosting/moved?project=gdata-java-client but this page redirects me to a github project at https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client

Now, when I download the zip from that project, in the lib directory the jar I can only see is `gdata-spreadsheet-1.0.jar`.

Is it that I have to build the project myself? Isn't there anywhere from where the built library can be downloaded?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As the answers are supposed to be general and not for a specific individual, we avoid using salutations: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this one. "1-0" is the version of the client library and not the version of the API it supports (I know, it's confusing).

A look at the [version.properties](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/blob/master/java/version.properties) file, this client library should work with v3 of the Spreadsheet API.